# Add a user in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, save, addition, cakephp-2.x

There is a problem when I write an `add()` function for `UsersController`.

```php
public function add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->request->data['User']['book_id'] = $this->Book('id'); 
    if ($this->User->saveAssociated($this->request->data)){
      $this->request->data['User']['book_id'] = "ff";
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Save User'));
      return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User Error.')); 
  }
}
```

If I add a `User` I want to save the book ID in my `User` `book_id`.
Anyone know how to deal with this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding a new user, does he get to select a book from a drop down(in the form)? If so, `$this->request->data['User']['book_id']` will already contain the Book id.

There's no need to explicitly write `$this->request->data['User']['book_id'] = $this->Book('id');` like you have done.

The way I see it, the add.ctp view file should contain a select box containing a list of all books which the user can select. On selecting one of those and submitting the form, `$this->request->data['User']['book_id']` will automatically store the book_id, without having to write anything in the controller.

Please specify the add.ctp form fields so that I can assist you better.

Thanks!